# Add Reusable Content to a Wiki Page

Tags: reusable, wiki

I would like to insert a Reusable Content to my Wiki page (I would like to create a Navigation snippet, so I could include it in every subwiki page, where it's needed), I've created the Content in the Reusable Content list, but the button is disabled, I can't add it, can someone tell me what to do make it enabled?

Here is a screenshot: http://i52.tinypic.com/2qi73vp.png

The Publishing infrastructure is enabled, btw. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

Insert a Content Editor Web Part.  And then add the reusable content to that.  The wiki pages themselves don't support the reusable content, however they do support inserting webparts.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 5 years old but I just came across this. In SPO it appears that you cannot add Reusable Content to a content editor webpart or a list item.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a text file in **SiteAssets** library or any other library. Ex: /SiteAssets/ReusedContent.txt
2. Add a **Content Editor** webpart to the page
3. Edit the **Content Editor** webpart
4. Update "**Content Link To link to a text file, type a URL**." with **/SiteAssets/ReusedContent.txt**
5. Export this Content Editor webpart and import it to all pages you would like to reuse the content.

Hope it helps...